# How to index a virtual field that changes with respect to time

Tags: solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I have a virtual field `weight` that changes based on the difference in time between now and object created_at time. I want to update it in Sunspot every 2 hours, so I was planning to call `Topic.solr_index`.

However I think Sunspot will only index records which are marked dirty. So I guess this wouldn't work. My questions are:

- How to index this kind of non-dirty current-time-dependent fields in Sunspot
- How can I check that `weight` has been updated correctly in solr admin(or any other way to check indexing result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption was wrong.

If I have a weight method, which outputs true/false based on the current time (say true if now is the morning), eventhough the model is not marked dirty, Sunspot will still index that properly every time.